# TextWrangler: line-number in a replace string

Tags: replace, textwrangler

I'm looking for the best way to search all the occurrences of a string and replace them with something related to the line number.

For example, line **857** must become:

> z-index: 96;

where 96 = (**linenumber** +7) / 9.

And line **848** must become:

> z-index: 95;

where 95 = (**linenumber** +7) / 9.

[sample screenshot of my document](https://cldup.com/4rA8Ua-ky9.png)

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to switch half way through to some kind of spreadsheet application, please, read on.

Using TextWrangler (4.5.11) with grep enabled for searches:

- Start adding line numbers using TextWrangler's -> Text -> Add/Remove line numbers.
- Search for `^[[:digit:]]+ (?!z-index)(.*)$` and replace with `\t\1`.
- Search for `^([[:digit:]]+)` and replace with `=(\1+7)/9\t`.
- Mark everything and copy.

Sorry - no clue, how to calculate inside TextWrangler. Thus:

- Paste into some spreadsheet application. (Did test with Google table and Excel. Might need to adjust formula if other software is being used.)
- Wait for the formulas to be calculated.
- Mark everything and copy.
- Go back to TextWrangler. Paste replacing original selection.
- Verify the calculations' result to persist.
- Search for `^([[:digit:]]+)\t(\s+z-index: )0;` and replace with `\2\1`.
- Verify the file's content (and provide more detail if necessary to address the problem in full; significant chunk of data would facilitate proper testing…).

Comment: @JeanPaul Did you have a chance to give the above a try? Any adjustments you would like to see?